# How to transform a mutation inside a function composition to a local, non-observable one?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

`Task` is a monadic type that represents sequentially executed asynchronous computations. As with `Promise` there is a combinator similar to `Promise.all`, but which runs in sequence as said before:

```js
const TYPE = Symbol.toStringTag;

const struct = type => cons => {
  const f = x => ({
    ["run" + type]: x,
    [TYPE]: type,
  });

  return cons(f);
};

const Task = struct("Task") (Task => k => Task((res, rej) => k(res, rej)));

const arrFold = alg => zero => xs => {
  let acc = zero;

  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
    acc = alg(acc) (xs[i]);

  return acc;
};

const tMap = f => tg =>
  Task((res, rej) => tg.runTask(x => res(f(x)), rej));

const tOf = x => Task((res, rej) => res(x));

const delay = (ms, x) =>
  Task(f => setTimeout(f, ms, x), f => f(x));

const tAnd = tf => tg =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    tf.runTask(f =>
      tg.runTask(g =>
        res([f, g]), rej),
        rej));

const tAll =
  arrFold(acc => tf =>
    tMap(([xs, x]) =>
      (xs.push(x), xs)) // A
        (tAnd(acc) (tf)))
          (tOf([]));

const main = tAll([
  delay(200, 'a'),
  delay(500, 'b'),
  delay(100, 'c')]);
  
const main2 = tAll([
  delay(100, 'd')]);

main.runTask(console.log, console.error); // ["d"]
main2.runTask(console.log, console.error); // ["d", "a", "b", "c"]
```

The mutation in line `A` evidently causes a side effect. I can avoid it by replaing the destructive push with `Array.prototype.concat`.

However, `concat` is incredible inefficient. Say I have to edit 1,000,000 files. Well, you can say that that would be slow anyway, as each file is processed in sequence. But I bet this problem pops up in other scenarios too.

Is there a way to transform this mutation to a local, non-observable one?

Btw., I know persistant data structures would allow me to use `concat` more efficiently, but i'd like to avoid them in Javascript.

Comment: so complicated - any applications?

Comment: Would wrapping `tOf([])` in a function (`() => tOf([])`) and having `arrFold` initialize `acc = zero()` do the trick? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @user3297291 No, that's it. It's a bit odd, but it's also Javascript, right? Please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `arrFold` as a curried function. You then use it to define `tAll` by passing it two out of the three required arguments:

```
const arrFold = alg => zero => xs => { /* ... */ }
const tAll = arrFold
  (acc => tf => tMap(([xs, x]) => (xs.push(x), xs)) (tAnd(acc) (tf)))
  (tOf([]));
```

Here, you basically bake an array instance in to your `tAll` function to be used as the `zero` whenever you use it to fold an array of tasks.

Two solutions I can think of are to (1) either make `arrFold` use a "lazy" `zero` argument:

```
const arrFold = alg => zero => xs => { 
  let acc = zero();
  /* ... */
}

const tAll = arrFold
  (/* ... */)
  (() => tOf([]))
```

```js
const TYPE = Symbol.toStringTag;

const struct = type => cons => {
  const f = x => ({
    ["run" + type]: x,
    [TYPE]: type,
  });

  return cons(f);
};

const Task = struct("Task") (Task => k => Task((res, rej) => k(res, rej)));

const arrFold = alg => zero => xs => {
  let acc = zero();

  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
    acc = alg(acc) (xs[i]);

  return acc;
};

const tMap = f => tg =>
  Task((res, rej) => tg.runTask(x => res(f(x)), rej));

const tOf = x => Task((res, rej) => res(x));

const delay = (ms, x) =>
  Task(f => setTimeout(f, ms, x), f => f(x));

const tAnd = tf => tg =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    tf.runTask(f =>
      tg.runTask(g =>
        res([f, g]), rej),
        rej));

const tAll =
  arrFold(acc => tf =>
    tMap(([xs, x]) =>
      (xs.push(x), xs)) // A
        (tAnd(acc) (tf)))
          (() => tOf([]));

const main = tAll([
  delay(200, 'a'),
  delay(500, 'b'),
  delay(100, 'c')]);
  
const main2 = tAll([
  delay(100, 'd')]);

main.runTask(console.log, console.error); // ["d"]
main2.runTask(console.log, console.error); // ["d", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Or, (2), have `tAll` make a new `zero` argument whenever you call it:

```
const tAll = tasks => arrFold
  (/* ... */)
  (tOf([]))
  (tasks)
```

```js
const TYPE = Symbol.toStringTag;

const struct = type => cons => {
  const f = x => ({
    ["run" + type]: x,
    [TYPE]: type,
  });

  return cons(f);
};

const Task = struct("Task") (Task => k => Task((res, rej) => k(res, rej)));

const arrFold = alg => zero => xs => {
  let acc = zero;

  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
    acc = alg(acc) (xs[i]);

  return acc;
};

const tMap = f => tg =>
  Task((res, rej) => tg.runTask(x => res(f(x)), rej));

const tOf = x => Task((res, rej) => res(x));

const delay = (ms, x) =>
  Task(f => setTimeout(f, ms, x), f => f(x));

const tAnd = tf => tg =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    tf.runTask(f =>
      tg.runTask(g =>
        res([f, g]), rej),
        rej));

const tAll = tasks =>
  arrFold(acc => tf =>
    tMap(([xs, x]) =>
      (xs.push(x), xs)) // A
        (tAnd(acc) (tf)))
          (tOf([]))
            (tasks);

const main = tAll([
  delay(200, 'a'),
  delay(500, 'b'),
  delay(100, 'c')]);
  
const main2 = tAll([
  delay(100, 'd')]);

main.runTask(console.log, console.error); // ["d"]
main2.runTask(console.log, console.error); // ["d", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: The latter approach isn't recursion, it's just eta abstraction. Sorry for the confusion.